# Format decimal output without truncating zero

Tags: java, android, string

I am displaying the Price of an Item in android Java Like this

```
mItemPrice.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d", price));
```

The problem with this:
**If the price is 1.550 The output is 1.55**
However I like to keep the last zero as (1.550). Any Suggestion, how can I do it.

Comment: can you tell what is the data type for price?

Comment: it is of type double

Comment: I dont think double will store the zeros after decimal. You will have to check how you are reading the values and make sure you directly read it as String and not as double.

Comment: Your code throws `IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double` for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
mItemPrice.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.3f", price));
```

You can find a complete description of the formatter [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax), basically `%.3f` means print a decimal number with exactly 3 values after the decimal separator.

Comment: Question: What I don't know the number of digits after decimal. Say if the number is 1.5550

Comment: If the number is 1.5550 it will print 1.555. If the number is 1.55478547854 it will print 1.554